# How to resolve the extension path in an Html tag created with Typoscript - TYPO3

Tags: path, typo3, typoscript, favicon, typo3-extensions

I am trying to add the following line in the Head

```
<link rel="manifest" href="path_myext/site.webmanifest">
```

But I can't resolve the file path.

With images is resolve the next way:

```
1 = IMG_RESOURCE
1.file = {$var.filepaths.img}/apple-touch-icon.png
1.stdWrap.wrap = <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="|">
```

But this way not work with that line

```
2 = IMG_RESOURCE
2.file = {$var.filepaths.img}/site.webmanifest
2.stdWrap.wrap = <link rel="manifest" href="|">
```

I also used the TEXT type but it prints exactly the $var

```
2 = TEXT
2.value = <link rel="manifest" href="{$var.filepaths.img}/site.webmanifest">
```

```
<link rel="manifest" href="{EXT:myext/Resources/Public/images}/site.webmanifest">
```

$var is created in constants.ts

```
var {
    filepaths {     
        img  = EXT:myext/Resources/Public/images
    }
}
```

The expected result is this

```
<link rel="manifest" href="path_myext/site.webmanifest">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this documentation can help you:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#insertdata

Example:

```
# TEXT is already stdWrapable, so we can also use insertData right away
20 = TEXT
20.value = <link rel="preload" href="{path : EXT:site/Resources/Public/Fonts/Roboto.woff2}" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
20.insertData = 1
```

Comment: This (and many more) getText-properties are worth a look and are documented here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Data.html#path